# Evans' Partial Differential Equations p.136 3.4.1 Shocks, entropy condition

Tags: partial-differential-equations, hyperbolic-equations

In Evans' PDE textbook p. 136, **3.4.1 Shocks, entropy condition**:

> More precisely, assume
>   $$
> \left\lbrace
> \begin{aligned}
> &v : \Bbb R\times [0, \infty) \to \Bbb R \text{ is smooth, with}\\
> &\text{compact support}
> \end{aligned}
> \right.
>  \tag{2}
> $$
>
> We call $v$ a *test function*. Now multiply the PDE $u_t + F(u)_x = 0$ by $v$ and integrate by parts:
>   $$
> \begin{aligned}
> 0&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(u_t+F(u)_x)\, v\, dx dt& \\
> &=-\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}uv_t\, dxdt - \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}uv\, dx|_{t=0} \\ &\qquad - \int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}F(u)v_x\, dxdt .
> \end{aligned}
> \tag{3}
> $$

But my computation is 
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(u_t+F(u)_x)v dxdt=\\-\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}uv_t dxdt+\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}uv dx|_{t=0}^{\infty}\\+\int_{0}^{\infty}F(u)v dtdx|_{-\infty}^{\infty}-\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}F(u)v_x dxdt$$

How to get the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $v$ is smooth with compact support, its values at $x = \pm\infty$ and $t = +\infty$ are zero. This is also true for $uv$, $F(u)v$, etc. Hence, the additional terms obtained in your (correct) computation vanish, and the formula $(3)$ of Evans' book is obtained.